# The procedure is being created successfully in mySQL server but its not selecting any rows

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter $$

create procedure increase_charge()
begin
declare v_name VARCHAR(120);
declare v_oldchg VARCHAR(120);
declare v_newchg VARCHAR(120);
declare not_found int default 0;
declare c_nur cursor for select n_name,n_charge 
     from Nurses
     Where n_charge < 70;
declare continue handler for not found set not_found = 1;
 
open c_nur;
loop_label:
loop
fetch c_nur into v_name,v_oldchg;

if not_found = 1 then LEAVE loop_label; END IF;

set v_newchg= v_oldchg+( v_oldchg*0.20);

UPDATE Nurses 
SET n_charge = v_newchg
WHERE Nurses.n_name = v_name;

SELECT'Nurse name',ifnull(v_name, '');
SELECT'Old change per hour',ifnull(v_oldchg, '');
SELECT'New charge per hour',ifnull(v_newchg, '');

end loop;

close c_nur;

end;

delimiter;

call increase_charge;
```

Comment: the call statement is invalid it should ate lease be call increase_charge() and the end should be followed be $$

Comment: I did the same thing but it still did not work.
please bear in mind that when I create the procedure it shows that 0 rows has been selected.

Comment: Then provide sample data and expected outcome as text in the question.

Comment: Sample data


      N_ID N_NAME                 N_CHARGE
---------- -------------------- ----------
       111 Tasha                        70
       110 Borsa                        60
       120 Jamila                       60


Sample output

call increase_charge();
Nurse name Borsa
Old change per hour 50
New charge per hour 60
Nurse name Jamila
Old change per hour 50
New charge per hour 60

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code and it works as expected with the minor syntax corrections.

```
drop table if exists nurses;
create table nurses(n_name varchar(3),n_charge int);
insert into nurses values('aaa',10),('bbb',80);

drop procedure if exists increase_charge;

delimiter $$

create procedure increase_charge()
begin
declare v_name VARCHAR(120);
declare v_oldchg VARCHAR(120);
declare v_newchg VARCHAR(120);
declare not_found int default 0;
declare c_nur cursor for select n_name,n_charge 
     from Nurses
     Where n_charge < 70;
declare continue handler for not found set not_found = 1;
 
open c_nur;
loop_label:
loop
fetch c_nur into v_name,v_oldchg;

if not_found = 1 then LEAVE loop_label; END IF;

set v_newchg= v_oldchg+( v_oldchg*0.20);

UPDATE Nurses 
SET n_charge = v_newchg
WHERE Nurses.n_name = v_name;

SELECT'Nurse name',ifnull(v_name, '');
SELECT'Old change per hour',ifnull(v_oldchg, '');
SELECT'New charge per hour',ifnull(v_newchg, '');

end loop;

close c_nur;

end $$

delimiter ;

call increase_charge();

select * from nurses;

+--------+----------+
| n_name | n_charge |
+--------+----------+
| aaa    |       12 |
| bbb    |       80 |
+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

BTW this can be done with a simple update statement

```
update nurses
set n_charge = n_charge + (n_charge * .2)
where n_charge < 70;
```